# using specialized templates to overload function based on return type

Tags: c++, templates, reference, overloading, return-type

I am trying to return a reference to a value in an array based on the return type. I read somewhere that c++ did not support overloading using return types but that specialized templates could be used.

I tried and failed.. could you help me figure out what i am doing wrong?

This is what i thought I should to:

```
uint16_t var_uint16[10];
float var_float[10];

template<class T>
T& Memory(int index) {  }

template<>
uint16_t& Memory<uint16_t>(int index) { return var_uint16[index]; }

template<>
float& Memory<float>(int index) { return var_float[index]; }
```

And call it like this:

```
float a = 10.0;
Memory(1) = a;     // Should set var_float[1] to 10.0
```

The code above produces the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Memory(int)'
candidate is:
template<class T> T& Memory(int)
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
```

Comment: Well, you won't like it, but you can do this, you just have to explicitly indicate which function to call: Memory<float>(1) = a;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only overload cast operator based on return type. You can overload =operator to support your exact semantics

```
struct Element {
    operator uint16_t&()
    {
        return var_uint16[i];
    }

    operator float&()
    {
        return var_float[i];
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator=(T t)
    {
        T& val = *this;
        val = t;
    }
    int i;
};
inline Element Memory(int i) { return Element{i}; }

float a = 10.0;
Memory(1) = a;

float& x = Memory(1);
x = 10.0
```

Comment: It compiles fine when used with Memory(1), but as soon as i pass a variable as parameter it fails with: conflicting declaration 'M var_id', 'var_id' has a previous declaration as 'int var_id'.. Any idea why? (Still trying to understand what actually happens..)

Comment: it looks like it is taking Memory(x) as declaration of variable x for type Memory

Comment: Removed the constructor call Memory, renamed struct and made Memory factory method instead. It works with variable now.

Comment: Also if you are not using c++11, then function Memory would be: inline Element Memory(int i) { Element e = {i}; return e; }